# Highcharts Erroneous Data Points Formatted in Charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using highstocks to display data retrieved from a Federal Reserve API.  The data is yearly values from 1929-2012.  I have two of what I think are exact jsfiddle examples that are giving  different and erroneous results.

Version 1: http://jsfiddle.net/johngalt/NeC54/
Version 1a: http://jsfiddle.net/johngalt/LdWh4/

My question is why are the two sets of code yielding different results?  In addition, I calculate Epoch Time from the string that the API is passes me like this in Rails:

```
tempDateHolder = DateTime.strptime(observation.date.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d').to_i * 1000
```

The date's original form is "1932-01-01"

Comment: It's possible that the data isn't sorted by timestamp, and that you have duplicate timestamps. Your data should be in ascending order by date, and no duplicate timestamps on the same axis.

Comment: Since the data starts in 1929, the numbers before 1970 are negative until they approach zero and then are positive.  So since the date is always January 1, of a given year there will be numbers that are the same but for them being negative.

Comment: But in both your examples you have: -1293840000000 twice. And they are not in date order.

Comment: Thanks @StuR I completely missed that the data was being duplicated in the db.